# Java making maths methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm creating some method which do simple maths calculations. I have a square, cube and hypercube method. And I'm trying to create a power method which when n = 2, calls the square method, when n = 3, calls the cube method etc. I want this power method to return an int k. However the value of k doesn't seem to be travelling behond the if statements. Any suggestions?

```
  public int power(int x, int n){
    int k;
    if (n==2){
        k = square(x);
    }
    else if (n==3){
        k = cube(x);
    }
    else if (n==4){
        k = hypercube(x);
    }
    else if (n==1){
        k = x;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you pass an `n` value of `0`?  `5`?

Comment: what do you mean that the value hasn't been `"travelling beyond the if statements"`  is your method returning `0` or whatever java defaults ints to be?

Comment: What do you mean _"the value of k doesn't seem to be traveling beyond the if statements"_? How do you know?

Comment: Use a debugger to track the value of k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, I get from the compiler "error: variable k might not have been initialized". I'm guessing this is what you mean. This is because, like the error suggests, if `n` isn't in the range 1 - 4, `k` is never explicitly set to any value. Here's one way to fix the problem, which allows the method to work for larger values of `n` (as long as you don't loop past Integer.MAX_VALUE):

```
public int power(int x, int n){
    int k;
    if (n==2){
        k = square(x);
    }
    else if (n==3){
        k = cube(x);
    }
    else if (n==4){
        k = hypercube(x);
    }
    else if (n==1){
        k = x;
    }
    else {
        k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            k *= x;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work although when I call the power method I'm getting a red flag which tells me I have to set the power method to static, cannot make a static reference to non static power method?

Comment: Either change `power` to a static method (`public static int power`) or create an instance of the class it's in before using it. You might need to make `square`, `cube`, and `hypercube` static, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for this, like here (I hope I got it right).

```
public int power(int x, int n){
    if(n==0) return 1;
    int k = x;
    while(--n > 0) {
        k *= x;
    }
    return k;
}
```

You might also add support for negative powers, but then you'd need some other return type (eg. float or double).

But honestly, why don't you just use `Math.pow()`?

Answer (score 0):

This code does not compile since k has not been initialized and you get compilation error at `return k;`. if you want to initialize with 0, use  `int k=0` in the declaration

Answer (score 0):

`k` will be "known" by the end of the method if it was assigned along the way. Perhaps you enforce that no invalid value of `k` can be passed in, then it should do what you want it to do:

```
public int power(int x, int n){
    if (n < 1 || n > 4){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n is invalid :" + n);
    }
    int k = 0;
    if (n==2){
        k = square(x);
    }
    else if (n==3){
        k = cube(x);
    }
    else if (n==4){
        k = hypercube(x);
    }
    else if (n==1){
        k = x;
    }
    return k;
}
```

You should also make sure that `x` is always valid.